# are these some kind of built-in CSS classes?

Tags: css

I see CSS code in my web page like below:

```
<ul tabindex="0" class="level1 static" ...>
```

But in the css file referenced by the page, I didn't find the **level1** or **static** class name.

Are they some kind of built-in CSS classes?

Is there any formal list of the built-in CSS classes?

Comment: Are they referenced by JavaScript? CSS isn't the only thing that could look for class names.

Comment: It must be applied by some of your js code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do it. Use the IHtmlDocument2 interface. With reference to this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292485

I will share my code snippet shortly.

Comment: I am downvoting this answer because the link is broken, the snippet was never shared, and "I have figured out a way to do it" doesn't seem to be related to the original question. I will remove my downvote and possibly upvote if the answer is improved.

Answer (score 2):

No they are not built in classes, CSS has nothing called built in unless and until you use external references like `twitter bootstrap framework`, these are probably redundant one's, you can remove them safely if your stylesheet doesn't have them

**Note**: Javascripts may use those classes, so are there any javascripts? I recommend you to check those too.

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't any built in ones, but javascript commonly adds and removes them.

Classes aren't just for CSS, they are just a way to store data.

Nowadays by the way, it's considered better practice to use data attributes to store data rather than classes where appropriate.